# NestJS does not connect with MongoDB when using Docker containers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, nestjs

NestJS App connect normally with MongoDB

but, after creating a docker containers for them

NestJS does not connect with MongoDB

here's Dockerfile

```
# Base image
FROM node:16-alpine

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
COPY package*.json ./

# Install app dependencies
RUN yarn install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

# Creates a "dist" folder with the production build
RUN yarn build
```

here's the docker compose file

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data_container:/data/db

  api:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - ${PORT}:${PORT}
    command: npm run start:dev
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

volumes:
  mongodb_data_container:
```

here's .env file

```
PORT=3000
DB_CONNECTION_STRING=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db-name
```

here's the connect method inside NestJS app

```
MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.DB_CONNECTION_STRING)
```

Answer (score 0):

For everyone facing the same issue

replace mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db-name

with mongodb://mongodb:27017/db-name